# Opening & Lockingdown SSH

Tags: ssh

I am about to port forward my SSH service through my NAT router enabling access on the WAN side. What steps should I take to lock down SSH service before port forwarding.

**I am currently**:

- Using a strong password - Could/Should I be using key files?
- Using a non-standard port

**Ideas**:

- Is there anyway I can 'beef up' the encryption key size e.g. from 1024-bit to 2048, I don't know what SSH uses?
- Can I implement any kind of anti-brute force protection?
- Can I/Do I need to implement some kind of mutual authentication?

What else should I do? I am using OpenSSH on Linux.

Comment: If you're curious about anti-brute-force protection, look up fail2ban. Otherwise, this isn't a specific question. It's far too open-ended for [SU]. You're going to get lots of opinions and potentially debate, which we try to stay away from here. If you need help about implementing your "Ideas", each one would stand as an individual question by itself (i.e., "How do I increase the keysize that OpenSSH uses?") - Just make sure it hasn't been asked before.

Answer (score 0):

> •Using a strong password - Could/Should I be using key files?

Key files will provide more protection than a password - ***IF*** you passphrase-protect your private key (the key you use on the client end) with a very good password.

> •Using a non-standard port

You'll substantially reduce the number of random attackers trying to log in by doing this.  It's "security by obscurity" but can make sure your log files are cleaner.  I do it.

> •Is there anyway I can 'beef up' the encryption key size e.g. from 1024-bit to 2048, I don't know 
>   what SSH uses?

When you use the `ssh-keygen` command to make your keys, you can specify any key length you like.  Longer keys cause connection initiation to be slower.  If you don't have a fast connection to your server a really long key can prevent you from being connected due to timeouts, i.e. over cellular networks.

> •Can I implement any kind of anti-brute force protection?

`fail2ban` is a good idea as @Darth Android mentions above.

> •Can I/Do I need to implement some kind of mutual authentication?

The key system used by `ssh` already provides this.  An SSH client should tell you the fingerprint of the server, and you should compare this with the actual server fingerprint that you recorded earlier to verify.

Other things you should do:

- apply all OpenSSH updates as soon as you can
- set the config file to disallow root login.  That way root access needs 2 passwords, one to get into `ssh` and an `su` or such once you are in.

Comment: using key-files provide more protection no matter of how good the passphrase to protect the private keys is: the attack scenario is guessing the passphrase / key to get into the server (in this case the home router).  it's better because it has more randomness and is longer than any passphrase a usual use can come up with. sure, it's wise to protect the private key, but in general using keys instead of passphrases is more secure per se.